# Pass custom <li> attribute to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a basic dropdown and each dropdown option has specific attributes. I'd like to pass those attributes (data name, description, and value) to a javascript function. code is below the console says "undefined " for everything I'm trying to pass. I've already tried changing `.data()` to `.attr()`. I really need something clean and simple. thanks!

### HTML

```
<label class="dropdown" style="float: left" >
    <div class="dd-button">Select a Plan</div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="dd-input" id="test">
    <ul id="dropdown" class="dd-menu">
        <li data-description="description." data-name="Web" data-value="mmk">2</li>
        <li data-description="description." data-name="Basic" data-value="basic">3</li>
        <li data-description="description." data-name="Plus" data-value="plus">4</li>
    </ul>
</label>
```

### JS

```
var PLAN_CONFIG = {
    id: '',
    billing: '',
    name: '',
    description: '',
    payment: true,
    panelLabel: 'Confirm',
};

$('#dropdown').click(function () {
    PLAN_CONFIG.id = $(this).data('value');
    PLAN_CONFIG.name = $(this).data('name');
    PLAN_CONFIG.description = $(this).data('description');
    console.log(PLAN_CONFIG);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you assign the click event handler to `#dropdown`, `this` in the callback function will be `#dropdown` too. You should assign the event handler to `li` elements instead:

```
$('#dropdown li').click(function () {
```

Demo:

```js
var PLAN_CONFIG = {
    id: '',
    billing: '',
    name: '',
    description: '',
    payment: true,
    panelLabel: 'Confirm',
};

$('#dropdown li').click(function () {
    PLAN_CONFIG.id = $(this).data('value');
    PLAN_CONFIG.name = $(this).data('name');
    PLAN_CONFIG.description = $(this).data('description');
    console.log(PLAN_CONFIG);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label  class="dropdown" style = "float: left" >
    <div class="dd-button"> Select a Plan </div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="dd-input" id="test">
        <ul id = "dropdown" class="dd-menu">
            <li data-description = "description." data-name = "Web" data-value="mmk" >2 </li>
            <li data-description = "description." data-name = "Basic" data-value="basic" >3 </li>
            <li data-description = "description." data-name = "Plus" data-value="plus" >4</li>
        </ul>
</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this selector `'#dropdown li'`.

Your current code is binding the click event to your element `dropdown` rather than your `li` elements.

```js
var PLAN_CONFIG = {
  id: '',
  billing: '',
  name: '',
  description: '',
  payment: true,
  panelLabel: 'Confirm',
};

$('#dropdown li').click(function() {
  PLAN_CONFIG.id = $(this).data('value');
  PLAN_CONFIG.name = $(this).data('name');
  PLAN_CONFIG.description = $(this).data('description');
  console.log(PLAN_CONFIG);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="dropdown" style="float: left">
    <div class="dd-button"> Select a Plan </div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="dd-input" id="test">
        <ul id = "dropdown" class="dd-menu">
            <li data-description = "description." data-name = "Web" data-value="mmk" >2 </li>
            <li data-description = "description." data-name = "Basic" data-value="basic" >3 </li>
            <li data-description = "description." data-name = "Plus" data-value="plus" >4</li>
        </ul>
</label>
```